# Finding intervals using the Contraction Mapping Theorem

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to identify an interval $[a, b]$ for which the Contraction Mapping Theorem guarantees convergence to the positive fixed point (or verify that there is no such interval) for the function $g(x) = x^3+3x^2-3$.

Clearly, the only positive fixed point is $1$. However, according to the mean value theorem, the positive interval will be $[0,0.464]$. Does that mean that there is no such interval guaranteed by the CMT for the function $g(x)$? Am I thinking about this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $g(x) : I \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz iff there exists a $k>0$ such that:

$$k = \sup_{x \in I} |g'(x)|.$$

Let $a = 1 - \delta$, $b = 1+ \delta$ and $I = [a, b]$. The derivative of $g$ is:

$$g'(x) = 3x^2 + 6x.$$

$g'(x)$ as a stationary point at $x=-1$ (absolute minimum). In addition, 
$g''(x) > 0$ for all $x > -1.$
Then, for $1- \delta > -1 \Rightarrow 0 < \delta < 2$, we have that:

$$g'(1-\delta) < g'(1+\delta)$$

and hence

$$k = \sup_{x \in I} |g'(x)| = |g'(1+\delta)| = |3(1+\delta)^2 + 6(1 + \delta)| = (1+\delta)|9 + 3\delta|.$$

As a consequence:

$$k \in [9, 30].$$

[$k$ is also the contraction factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping), but it is always bigger than $1$, and hence, there is no basin of attraction for $x^* = 1.$

---

Alternatively, notice that, for $x^* = 1$:
$$g'(x^*) = 3\cdot 1^2 + 6 \cdot 1 = 9 > 1.$$

This demonstrates that there is no neighborhood of $x^*$, let's say $I$, such that:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} x_n = x^* ~\text{provided that}~ x_0 \in I \setminus \{x^*\},$$
where

$$x_{n+1} = g(x_{n}).$$

Sources for the latter argument are [here](https://www3.diism.unisi.it/~mocenni/lab04122017.pdf) and [here](http://cse.lab.imtlucca.it/~bemporad/teaching/ac/pdf/04a-TD_sys.pdf), among the thousands found on Google.